# RegisterHotKey() not detecting keypress

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, keypress, registerhotkey

So, I am trying to write a program that detects when the keycombination Control + C is pressed, I have read that the best way to do this is to use RegisterHotKey(). I have never used this before though so I am a little confused since my code isnt working. This is the solution I found online but it doesn't work. I have looked at the documentation but that hasn't helped either. this is my code:

```
AutoClicker::AutoClicker()
{
    clicker = std::thread(&AutoClicker::Clicker, this);
    enum {KEY_C = 1};
    RegisterHotKey(0, KEY_C, MOD_CONTROL, 0x5A);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
        PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
        switch (msg.message)
        {
        case WM_HOTKEY:
            if (msg.wParam == KEY_C)
            {
                printf("1 Pressed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `RegisterHotKey`.

Comment: It has a bool return value to indicate if it has succesfully registered the hotkey and it returns true here

Comment: `0x5A` is the virtual key code for the `Z` key. The `C` key is `0x43` instead.

Comment: *"Now press Control-Zee."* - "Control-Cee?" - *"Yes!"* - "OK. Doesn't work, Windows sucks".